# ruby and gem how do i roll them back or can i downgrade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i am working a project that has been giving me a headache on my desktop PC, im using Aptana Studio 3 Workspace. and i tried to run 'rake db:migrate' and gives me this: 
    rake aborted!
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.1/sqlite3_native

now, i tried somethings and nothing worked other people in my course havent seen this so i pushed what i had to github and pulled to my laptop and i ran the same command and it worked. i noticed that GEM version on my laptop was 2.0.15 and ruby version was 2.0.0p598. my desktop is running GEM v2.2.2 and ruby version 2.1.5p273. i have a hunch this is the issue. can i rollback so that my desktop is using the same versions as my latop ?

Comment: Did you try bundle install first ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first specify the gem version you want to install on your Gemfile.

```
gem "foo", "~> 0.3.4"
```

Then run `bundle update foo`

Then run `git diff Gemfile.lock`

To see what was changed.